# canon MG5320 will not print the magenta color

Tags: multi-function-printer

I have a brand new print head and new ink cartridges. It still will not print magenta. I have done all of the maintenance items several times and still no magenta. Is there anything else I can do before buying a new printer.

Comment: Contact Canon support.

Comment: Try to make a **direct copy** of a paper document, which does *not* use the PC's software. If that fails, then it's a *physical issue with the printer*, e.g., improperly seated connector, clogged print head, etc., which has **nothing to do with the PC or it's OS, drivers or software**.

Answer (score -1):

You can first try to update all possible software.

The Canon website lists downloads for the printer at the
[PIXMA MG5320 support page](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/mg-series-inkjet/mg5320?subtab=downloads-drivers).

Available are Windows drivers, firmware updater and some useful software.

If after having updated everything possible the printer still malfunctions,
then Canon Support is your last stop before shopping for a new printer.

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: Because this “answer” is really a comment that ultimately just repeats [what another actual comment has suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/1705085/canon-mg5320-will-not-print-the-magenta-color#comment2626076_1705085): Contact Canon support.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: I don't see any downloads link in the comment, which is *most of my answer*.

Comment: Harry, this is not the first time I have seen you post a comment as an answer, downvoted as such and then you act indignant. For someone with 392,000+ rep you really tend to be quite touchy and a bit clueless as to what a “comment” is versus an “answer” is. And on point: A link to drivers can be included in a comment. Unless  you are 100% sure that is the issue, saying someone should download drivers is not an answer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: You're highly exaggerating the uselessness of my answer. But I have already seen that there is no point in arguing with you.